# In the RxSwift-MVVM architecture what is the best way to trigger UI elements like pop-ups and indicators?

Tags: ios, mvvm, rx-swift

The question is - where it’s best to:

1. Call error handling popups
2. Show/Hide loading indicator

My app looks like this:

**ViewController** that subscribes to trigger of UI update when the model changes:

```
 var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
```

...

```
 viewModel.source.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (_ ) in
      self.tableView.reloadData()
     })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

**ViewModel**

```
     var source = Variable<[Student]>([])
```

And when initialized it fetches the source output

```
     api.fetchSourceOutput(id: id)
         .do(onError: { (error) in
                //show error here???
         })
         .catchErrorJustReturn([])
         .bind(to: source)
         .disposed(by: bag)
```

I can't just pass reference of ViewController into ViewModel, that would break the idea of it's independence from UI. Then how am I supposed to call error popup in view controller's view? Getting top view controller is not a good option either, because I might need specific view to show my popup in.
The loading indicator can be shown when onNext called inside viewModel and hidden onCompleted. But I again don't have reference to my view controller where my loading indicator reference resides.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Call error handling popups

Lets say you have some signal which starts api fetch

```
let someSignalWithIdToStartApiFetch = Observable.just(1)
```

Also, lets imagine that when you present some "retry request" popup on error and when user clicks on "retry" button you bind it to some observer. Then convert an observer to `Observable`. So you have some 2nd signal:

```
let someSignalWhenUserAsksToRetryRequestAfterError = Observable.just(())
```

When you need to retry a request you take the last id from `someSignalWithIdToStartApiFetch` this way:

```
let someSignalWithIdToRetryApiFetch = someSignalWhenUserAsksToRetryRequestAfterError
    .withLatestFrom(someSignalWithIdToStartApiFetch)
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

Then you combine both signals and make a request:

```
let apiFetch = Observable
    .of(someSignalWithIdToRetryApiFetch, someSignalWithIdToStartApiFetch)
    .merge()
    .flatMap({ id -> Observable<Response> in
        return api
            .fetchSourceOutput(id: id)
            .map({ Response.success($0) })
            .catchError({ Observable.just(Response.error($0)) })
    })
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

As you can see, the error is caught and converted to some result. For example:

```
enum Response {
    case error(Error)
    case success([Student])
    var error: Error? {
        switch self {
        case .error(let error):         return error
        default:                        return nil
        }
    }
    var students: [Student]? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let students):    return students
        default:                        return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then you work with successful result as usual:

```
apiFetch
    .map({ $0.students })
    .filterNil()
    .bind(to: source)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

But the error case should be bind to some observer which triggers popup to be shown:

```
apiFetch
    .map({ $0.error })
    .filterNil()
    .bind(to: observerWhichShowsPopUpWithRetryButton)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

So, when the pop up is shown and user clicks on "retry" - `someSignalWhenUserAsksToRetryRequestAfterError` will trigger and retry the request

> Show/Hide loading indicator

I use something like [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Services/ActivityIndicator.swift). It is a special structure which catches the activity of an observable. How you can use it?

```
let indicator = ActivityIndicator()
```

And some code from 1st part of the question.

```
let apiFetch = Observable
    .of(someSignalWithIdToRetryApiFetch, someSignalWithIdToStartApiFetch)
    .merge()
    .flatMap({ id -> Observable<[Student]> in
        return indicator
            .trackActivity(api.fetchSourceOutput(id: id))
    })
    .map({ Response.success($0) })
    .catchError({ Observable.just(Response.error($0)) })
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)
```

So, the activity of api fetch is tracked. Now you should show/hide your activity view.

```
let observableActivity = indicator.asObservable() // Observable<Bool>
let observableShowLoading = observableActivity.filter({ $0 == true })
let observableHideLoading = observableActivity.filter({ $0 == false })
```

Bind `observableShowLoading` and `observableHideLoading` to hide/show functions. Even if you have multiple request which might be executed simultaneously - bind them all to a single `ActivityIndicator`.

Hope it helps. Happy coding (^

Comment: Thank you. However, if apiFetch sends Error, the subscription will be terminated and no further button taps will repeat the process. To fix it, you can use "materialize, elements, errors" from RxSwiftExt.

Comment: @RealNmae well... **apiFetch** and error catching should be both inside **flatMap**. My mistake

Comment: Can you fix your answer to show me? Because as it looks to me, whenever you catch an error, the subscription completes and then disposes.

Comment: @RealNmae No, it doesn't works as you expect. You can catch an error! I will fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would make this changes in your `viewModel`:

```
// MARK: - Properties
let identifier = Variable(0)

lazy var source: Observable<[Student]> = identifier.asObservable()
    .skip(1)
    .flatMapLatest { id in 
        return api.fetchSourceOutput(id: id)
    }
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .share(replay: 1)

...

// MARK: - Initialization
init(id: Int) {
    identifier.value = id
    ...
}
```

Then, in your `ViewController`:

```
viewModel.source
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     }, onError: { error in 
        // Manage errors
     })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```